# seeking biological sound library

Tags: human, sound-effects

Hi All,

Does anyone know of a good biological\ anatomical sound library? Looking for internal human body sounds: perhaps recorded with a stethoscope

The closest thing I found was the sonivox anatomy library. Has anyone had good\bad experiences with this instrument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Native Instruments Kontakt? If you do, you can get Atom Hubs Microbiology.

It's only 10€.

http://www.atomhub.net/Microbiology.html

Human body consists mostly of water, so try to find suitable underwater sounds, drains, squishes...unless your aim is to go totally realistic?

Comment: update: I visited the sonivox site to take a look at Sonivox Anatomy. It was clear that Anatomy is more suited for music production. Another library that could be helpful to you is Hydrophonic by Rabbits Ear Audio. It's cheap at 50$   

http://rabbitearsaudio.com/rea003-hydrophonic/

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

I am not familiar with the sonivox anatomy library but I have made some of these sounds by micing up my own body; swallowing a lapel mic wrapped in a "finger condom??" and I have also put a rifle mic in my mouth and both recording came out amazingly. You can try this and see if it yeilds the results you have been searching for.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

[Stethoscope](http://www.asoundeffect.com/sound-library/stethoscope/) by ShapingWaves sounds like exactly what you were looking for. Adding this answer for completeness.